# Obtener hora inicial y final de Calendar para obtener su diferencia

Tags: java, android

He estado investigando bastante y me parece compleja la programación con java para utilizarla en Android studio. Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación en la cual el usuario pueda ingresar una fecha inicial y una final a través de este comando, el cual me muestra una pequeña aplicación para ingresar fecha y hora:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    tfechafinal.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo captar y convertir ese formato de fecha y hora para sacar la diferencia entre ambas, y mostrar el resultado en un textview?

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.